# Upload to Google Cloud Storage on local dev server gives wrong FileInfo.getGsObjectName() in upload handler

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have some file upload code that works on appspot.com but not on local Java dev server.

I am uploading to Google Cloud Storage, via:

```
String bucketName = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService().getDefaultGcsBucketName();
String uploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl(
       successUrl,
       UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName(bucketName)
);
```

in my upload handler (pointed to by "successUrl"), I try and read the newly uploaded blob from the GCS bucket. This is done like this:

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
Map<String, List<BlobKey>> uploads = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
Map<String, List<FileInfo>> files = blobstoreService.getFileInfos(req);
...
// use the FileInfo instance to do fileInfo.getGsObjectName()
...
GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(gcsFilename, 0, 1024 * 1024);
InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel));
```

up on the actual appengine instance, fileInfo.getGsObjectName() returns a working path like this:

```
/gs/myapp.appspot.com/L2F..LongIDHere...YmJV
```

which works and can be read, BUT, on the local dev server, I get something like:

```
/gs/app_default_bucket/fake-encoded_gs_key:YXB...LongIdHere...6de
```

which throws FileNotFoundException when tried read using the same code, that works on appEngine :-(

Comment: I have the same Problem. Did you find anything out. I found out that you can set the local storage file via <jvmFlag>-Ddatastore.backing_store=c:/temp/ds-maven.bin</jvmFlag>. Anyway that does not solve the problem.

Comment: @flosk8 Didn't solve problem as such no, but worked around it by checking if in development mode/server, and if so, loading blob via the BlobKey I get from blobstoreService.getUploads(req) instead. Loading it this way is not a streaming call though :(